# How to handle files and folders structure after dragging from Finder

Tags: cocoa, listview, draggable

I need to create a simple app that allow user to drag and drop multiple files and folder into some tree list and then display them to user.

A good example of what I need:

[image]

What best component should I use?
I just want to take advice before I start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too broad, but I'll point you the right direction:

•  For your data model, you'll want to use NSTreeController

•  For your view, NSOutlineView.

Here are some examples:

•  Apple's SourceView - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html

•  http://daemonconstruction.blogspot.in/2012/03/simplest-nstreecontroller-example.html

Comment: However, I trying to find some more simple examples.. Like just drag files to NSOutlineView and display them, with images.

Comment: Nitpick: NSTreeController is a controller object (and belongs to the controller layer of the MVC pattern), not a model object.